# Is html_attributions needed for unused photo content from Google Places Web Service API?

Tags: ios, web-services, google-places-api

I'm working on an iOS app that utilizes Google's Web Service API. When searching for places, each result contains a "photos" field. Within this photos field is a "html_attributions" field. I see that this "must be displayed" when searching for information about it, but I have not seen any conditions.

My question is, if I do not actually use the photo_reference/height/width fields inside the photos field, do I still need to display the html_attributions field to the user or is that only if content within the photos field is utilized/displayed?

I have yet to see any other location specific attributions using the web service for google places. Is there something else I might be missing?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html_attributions` inside the `photos` field only applies to that photo, not the rest of the search / details response.

The documentation on [Photo References](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos#photo_references) says (emphasis added by me):

> if the returned `photo` element includes a value in the `html_attributions` field, you will have to include the additional attribution in your application **wherever you display the image**.

Also, the documentation for Place Search Responses and Place Details Responses also describes the `html_attributions` on the root of the response differently to the one embedded inside the `photos`.

So yes, if you're not using the photo data, you don't have to display the attributions for that data.